# Getting Agent Info from API.ai fulfilment request

Tags: node.js, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Is there a way that I can get the API.ai agent information from the fulfillment request?

I am trying to capture any unique parameter from Node.js code that can be passed from Agent. This will be utilized for proceeding with the logic for multiple agents using a single code base.

For Amazon Alexa I could get the Skill Application Id from the session. Is there something similar in API.ai?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get agent id you can make something like this (using express framework):

```
app.post(`/:agent_id/webhook`, (req, res) => {
 const apiai_agent_id = req.params.agent_id;
 // webhook code...
});
```

And on fulfillment page in this case for each agent you have to specify it's own webhook URL like 
https://mywebhooks.com/55982e7c-db17-47ee-92bb-176476228942/webhook

(you can get agent id for webhook URL from browser's address bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API.AI's `sessionId` or `intentId` which will be unique across agents.  The `sessionId` and `intentId`* is sent with every fulfillment webhook request.  The of the JSON sent are similar to this:

```
{
  "id": "1a4b6209-51ec-47a1-a797-2e2f71926ac8",
  "sessionId": "1503343146047"
  ...
}
```

but will contain other elements as well.

*intentId may include additional numeric identifier after the intent ID if you are using [slot filling](https://api.ai/docs/examples/slot-filling)

Source: https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#request